# How to send a post request where it is neccesary to be logged in?

Tags: csrf

First off, this is in information security because the request may be vulnerable if I can figure out how to run it.

Second, the actual issue. I intercepted and copied a post request on an unnamed social media site that I may be able to send externally, but you have to be logged in to send it.

I tried intercepting the login post request, but it has CSRF protection.

Essentially, I am asking how I can go about sending this post request from a logged in session, ex. is there a chrome or firefox extension that allows you to send post requests from the current page/session that you're in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman for Chrome should be able to do what you need. Otherwise a simple solution is to just issue the post request through the Chrome console while you're already logged in.

Comment: Postman is making me log in first, but thanks for the Console tip, I'll use that.